# How to build and use libicu in webassembly

Tags: icu, webassembly

I am interested in the word iterator of the ICU63 library in a JavaScript project (in a browser). So after reading the docs, I believe that ICU uses UTF-16 by default which is the same than JS and it would avoid me to encode JS strings into something else.

First step was to build a wrapper with the only function that I need (I don't know yet if it is working):

```
#include "emscripten.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <unicode/brkiter.h>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/errorcode.h>

using namespace icu_63; 

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int splitWords(const char *locale, const uint16_t *text, uint16_t *splitted) {
    //Note that Javascript is working in UTF-16
    //icu::
    UnicodeString result = UnicodeString();
    UnicodeString visibleSpace = UnicodeString(" ");
    int32_t previousIdx = 0;
    int32_t idx = -1;

    //Create a Unicode String from input
    UnicodeString uTextArg = UnicodeString(text);
    if (uTextArg.isBogus()) {
        return -1; // input string is bogus
    }

    //Create and init the iterator
    UErrorCode err = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    BreakIterator *iter = BreakIterator::createWordInstance(locale, err);
    if (U_FAILURE(err)) {
        return -2; // cannot build iterator
    }
    iter->setText(uTextArg);

    //Iterate and store results
    while ((idx = iter->next()) != -1) {
        UnicodeString word = UnicodeString(uTextArg, idx, idx - previousIdx);
        result += word;
        result += visibleSpace;
        previousIdx = idx;
    }
    result.trim();
    //The buffer contains UTF-16 characters, so it takes 2 bytes per point
    memcpy(splitted, result.getBuffer(), result.getCapacity() * 2);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and looks good except that symbols are missing when trying to link because I have no clue about how to proceed.

LibICU looks to need a lot of builtin data. For my case, the frequency tables are mandatory for using the word iterator.

Should I try to copy my wrapper into the source folder and try to figure out how to use *emconfigure*. Or is it possible to link the libicu when I try to compile my wrapper? Second option looks like a waste of data as I am not interested by the larger portion of the lib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, the easiest way to deal with libraries is to build the libraries using `emconfigure`/`emmake` first then link them statically with your own code. Like the following:

```
$ emcc your_wrapper.cpp \
       your_compiled_libICU_static_lib.a \
       -o result.js
```

Compiling libraries using `emconfigure`/`emmake` sometimes quite hard because you may need to modify the source code in order to make it work in WebAssembly.

But...**Good news**! Emscripten provides ports of some popular and complicated libraries [and ICU is one of them](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/pull/7167).

You can compile your code without compiling ICU yourself using `-s USE_ICU=1` flag:

```
$ emcc your_wrapper.cpp \
       -s USE_ICU=1 \
       -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 \
       -std=c++11
```

The caveats is that Emscripten ICU port is ICU 62. So you need to change `using namespace icu_63;` to `using namespace icu_62;`

Answer (score 1):

While `-s USE_ICU=1` is convenient when you can easily modify your build flags, I've found it more convenient to install ICU from source, because I also had to build other libraries whose configure/make/build processes do not play nicely with `-s USE_ICU=1` (at least not without plenty of modification) and instead expect a more traditional way to find and link to the icu libs.

Unfortunately, building libicu does not seem to work with the usual `configure && make install` without some tweaking. To do that, first you have to do a "regular" native build (`./configure && make`) to create the necessary local files.

Then, if you do not need PTHREADS, you can build in a fairly straightforward manner as follows, assuming `/opt/wasm` is your PREFIX.

```
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/opt/wasm/lib/pkgconfig emconfigure ./configure --prefix=/opt/wasm --with-cross-build=`pwd` --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no --target=wasm32-unknown-emscripten --with-data-packaging=static --enable-icu-config --enable-extras=no --enable-tools=no --enable-samples=no --enable-tests=no
emmake make clean install
```

If you do need PTHREADS for some downstream consumer of the lib, you might have to rebuild the lib with that enabled from the get-go. This is trickier because configure scripts will break when they do their tests that require building and running C snippets, due to warnings about requiring additional node flags (see https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/15736), which to the `configure` scripts mean an error. The easiest solution I found was to temporarily modify `make_js_executable` in emcc.py:

```
  ...
  with open(script, 'w') as f:
    # f.write('#!%s\n' % cmd); ## replaced with the below line
    f.write('#!%s --experimental-wasm-threads --experimental-wasm-bulk-memory\n' % cmd)
    f.write(src)
  ...
```

With that hack done, you can proceed to something like the below (though possibly, not all of those thread-related flags are absolutely needed)

```
CXXFLAGS='-s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=8 -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -O3 -pthread' CFLAGS='-s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=8 -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -O3 -pthread' FORCE_LIBS='-s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=8 -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -pthread -lm' PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/opt/wasm/lib/pkgconfig emconfigure ./configure --prefix=/opt/wasm --with-cross-build=`pwd` --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no --target=wasm32-unknown-emscripten --with-data-packaging=static --enable-icu-config --enable-extras=no --enable-tools=no --enable-samples=no --enable-tests=no
emmake make clean install
```

After that, set your emcc.py back to its original state. Note that if you try to build the tools, they will fail-- I haven't yet found a solution to that-- but the lib does successfully install with the above.

Comment: I'm trying to build icu 59.2 and it's failing on the static data compilation. It's assembly which is probably why it's failing. Are you of aware of a way around this? `./out/tmp/icudt59l_dat.S:6:2: error: unknown directive .const`

Comment: @Kyle I believe you need to first build natively e.g. `cd icu4c/source && ./configure --disable-shared --enable-static && make install`. This builds various files, which I believe includes the ones related to this issue, that are reused for the emcc build. Then build the emcc version using something like:

Comment: `CXXFLAGS='...' CFLAGS='...' FORCE_LIBS='...' PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/opt/wasm/lib/pkgconfig emconfigure ./configure --prefix=/opt/wasm --with-cross-build=\`pwd\` --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no --target=wasm32-unknown-emscripten --with-data-packaging=static --enable-icu-config --enable-extras=no --enable-tools=no --enable-samples=no --enable-tests=no && emmake make clean install`